# Global search in Alfresco 4.2.c with accented characters

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share

Global search with accented characters workout doesn't work out of the box on my 4.2.c install, however whilst I was making some dev modifications and JVM modifications and by the time I had gotten around to working on the finding the cause and solving the issue a few days later it somehow started working. I have been unable to resolve or replicate the solution on my remote server however.
Looking at the logs in of both repository servers (identical content-stores) running the same search I get the following:

**local (OSX 10.7.5 running tomcat 7 with oracle JDK 1.7.0_25)**:

```
    //The request
    2013-09-15 22:57:50,835  DEBUG [webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] Processing request (GET) http://localhost:9090/alfresco/s/slingshot/search?site=&term=approuv%C3%A9&tag=&maxResults=251&sort=&query=&repo=false&rootNode=alfresco%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Fhome&alf_ticket=TICKET_a6d529d90810dc9c3844d50ef561340640a9bea9
    //The logs showing the query
         2013-09-15 22:57:50,839  DEBUG [web.scripts.RepositoryContainer] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] Begin retry transaction block: required,readonly
         2013-09-15 22:57:50,839  DEBUG [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] Executing script classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js
         2013-09-15 22:57:50,840  DEBUG [jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.calls] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] search.get.js Start
         2013-09-15 22:57:50,841  DEBUG [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] Unable to resolve specified root node reference: alfresco://company/home
         2013-09-15 22:57:50,841  DEBUG [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] Query:
        ((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (approuvé  AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden"
        Sortby: 
         2013-09-15 22:57:50,843  DEBUG [repo.jscript.Search] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] query=((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (approuvé  AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden" limit=502
 2013-09-15 22:57:50,923  DEBUG [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger] [http-bio-9090-exec-13] Processing resultset of length: 10
```

**remote (ubuntu 12.04 running tomcat 7 with orale jdk build 1.7.0_21)** :

```
//Requests are identical so skipped for brevity
//The query log
 2013-09-15 22:53:29,075  DEBUG [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger] [http-bio-8080-exec-9] Query:
((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (approuvÃ©  AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden"
Sortby: 
 2013-09-15 22:53:29,076  DEBUG [repo.jscript.Search] [http-bio-8080-exec-9] query=((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (approuvÃ©  AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden" limit=502
 2013-09-15 22:53:29,108  DEBUG [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger] [http-bio-8080-exec-9] Processing resultset of length: 0
```

The webscripts requests are almost identical (save for the ticket numbers) but locally the encoded accented characters are converted back to their original form which leads me to believe this could be an issue with the JVM. so I set the locale of the JVM (JAVA_OPTS) to french, but that yielded no results. Would be grateful for any hints or suggestions as to what else I could possibly check to compare the two.

Comment: Looks to me like something is getting UTF-8 data and thinking it's ISO-8859-1 or similar. Are you sure it's a real problem, and not just an artefact of how you're viewing the logs?

Comment: Yes. It is (or rather was) a problem. Thanks to your mention of "UTF-8" I had forgot to modify the encoding parameter of my remote setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to specify URIEncoding property of the tomcat connector. Thanks Gagravarr for the clue.
**Edit**: If Share and Alfresco reside in different tomcats, this needs to be set for both.